# Application going to background, data is not loaded

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I created a simple json application and working fine but when the app is going to background data is not loaded,some one please suggest me with code.

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getReviews?location=Rome&category=poi")!) { (data, response , error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
    if let resultArray = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
        for jsonreviews in resultArray {
            let review = Review()
            review.rating = jsonreviews["rating"] as? Int ?? 0
            review.text = jsonreviews["text"] as! String
            review.time = jsonreviews["time"] as! String
            reviews.append(review)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableview.reloadData()   // if you use tableview
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: I notice that you're updating `reviews` on a background thread. If your `UITableViewDataSource` methods are referencing this, you really should build a local array, and then copy that to your data source on the main thread (or synchronize your access to this somehow). Also, is `reviews` a global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution, if you only need an extra few minutes to finish the request, is to request the OS a little time to finish this. See [Background Execution: Executing Finite-Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).

So, to tell the OS that you might want a little extra time to run the request if the app happens to be suspended while the task is running, you can do:

```
var backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "com.domain.app.data") {
    // do whatever clean up you want before your app exits

    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

And, when the task is done:

```
if backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

Thus:

```
var backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "com.domain.app.data") {
    // do whatever clean up you want before your app exits

    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getReviews?location=Rome&category=poi")!) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error != nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        return
    }

    if let resultArray = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [[String: Any]] {
        for jsonreviews in resultArray {
            let review = Review()
            review.rating = jsonreviews["rating"] as? Int ?? 0
            review.text = (jsonreviews["text"] as! String)
            review.time = (jsonreviews["time"] as! String)
            reviews.append(review)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableview.reloadData()   // if you use tableview
        }
    }

    if backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
}
task.resume()
```

---

If you think you'll need more than a few minutes to finish the query, you can implement background `URLSession`, though that might be overkill for this scenario. It requires quite a few changes including:

- Use delegate-based `URLSession`;
- Use download task rather than data task;
- Make sure to implement app delegate method to respond to completion of background network request;
- etc.

Comment: i did not find any difference while i am using  delegate based URLSession and download task

Comment: @udaykumar - Did you use background `URLSessionConfiguration` when you instantiate your `URLSession`? Did you implement `handle​Events​For​Background​URLSession` call in your app delegate? Did you call the saved completion handler in your `url​Session​Did​Finish​Events`?

Comment: yes,I did but I did not call URL sessions did finish events

Comment: You don't call `url​Session​Did​Finish​Events`. You implement it in your `URLSessionDelegate` and the OS calls it. Typically you just have your implementation call the completion handler that was passed to you in `handle​Events​For​Background​URLSession`.

Comment: But let's step away from that for a second and look at your statement, "when the app is going to background data is not loaded" ... If an app is in background, if you're only using it a variable (which is lost when the app finally is suspended) that your `UITableViewDataSource` uses, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "not loaded".

Comment: I mean task is not downloaded when it is in background

Comment: Two things: 1. How are you testing "when in background"? You're not killing the app by double tapping the home button and then swiping up on the app, are you? That operation not only kills the app, but tells the OS to stop everything associated with that app (including any and all background operation). 2. If that's not it, then, you'll just have to create an [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because background sessions are very reliable and we certainly can't diagnose your problem if we can't see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Downloading in background using Swift 3.0](https://medium.com/@piyush.dez/downloading-in-background-using-swift-3-0-f770531db619)